# installed apache with brew but will not start - getting httpd (pid 89) already running

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew

Apache with brew worked before, but it has stoped now, no idea why.

```
$ sudo apachectl start
httpd (pid 89) already running
```

But its not running, http://localhost gives me: "This site can’t be reached"

when I do:

```
$ ps aux | grep httpd
```

it shows nothing

when I do:

```
$ lsof -i TCP:80
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google    308 darko  106u  IPv4 0x98978f46d14516f9      0t0  TCP 192.168.1.5:50046->ec2-54-204-11-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: this is process 89: 
   0    89     1   0  9:29pm ??         0:01.70 /System/Library/CoreServices/launchservicesd

Comment: Have you tried doing a configtest?  "sudo apachectl configtest"

Comment: did now, looks fine

 sudo apachectl configtest

Syntax OK

Comment: Search for apache rather than httpd: ps -ef | grep apache

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry: you said it at the beginning: it's already running, so start won't work one way or another.  Use "restart" or "graceful" to restart apache.  Don't use start.